# Checking Ansible version(ansible --version) but getting following error

Tags: python, django, ansible, jinja2, constants

And Jinja2 modules Requirement already satisfied

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 60, in <module>
    import ansible.constants as C
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/constants.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2'
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a broken install. A dependency is missing. Try:

```
pip3 install jinja2
```

This is not really supposed to happen when you install ansible "normally". If the above does not fix your problem, I suggest you reinstall ansible from scratch on your system